# Python CSV data gathering

Tags: python, dataframe, read.csv

I have CSVs I need to gather from a file path called Finance Directory.
Within Finance Directory there are two different types of files, Account History and Milestone. Within the two types, they have about 6 different SLAs throughout the day for each CSV. I need BOTH Account History and Milestone files, however I don’t need all of the files each day. I need JUST the last of the day for both Account History and Timeliness. The last of the day naming convention follows _1500.csv, UNLESS there is a revision (in which case we want to capture  Account History and Timeliness files’ last file OR the revision associated). Some cases there will be just a final file for Account History, but a revised file for Timeliness. Is it possible to bring these into one csv with Python?

I tried doing a iloc to grab the last file each day. But I wasn’t successful. I think it may be some type of if statement with conditions around the naming convention.

“Grab _1500.csv UNLESS there is a _1500_revision1.csv” is essentially what I need.

I don’t need anything with any other numbers, _730 or _1200 or even _1200 for example. Just the _1500.csv OR if there is a _1500.csv with a revision (aka _1500_revision1.csv)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask